# android-6.0.1_r45 error: could not load boot.img

Tags: android, android-source

I have build the android-6.0.1_r45  system successful.But when I tried to flash it to nexus 5x, I found an error could not load boot.img.I checked my /generic fold,there is ramdisk.img,system.img and userdata.img. Where is the boot.img?
WHY it is not exist in my build version.
I used this "lunch aosp_arm-eng"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.
"lunch aosp_arm-eng" refers to a complete build for the emulator,it is ONLY for emulator. And I want to falsh NEXUS 5X,so I MUST build with "aosp_bullhead-userdebug".OH,HOLYSHIT

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I was ready to flash the Neuxs 5X in a new terminal.

```
$ fastboot flashall -w
error: could not load boot.img
```

Here's my solution, **the key step is to run "lunch" cmd bofore you run "fastboot flashall -w"**. hope it helps.

```
$ cd android-7.1.1_r14/
$ lunch #select 21. aosp_bullhead-userdebug
$ cd out/target/product/bullhead
$ fastboot flashall -w
```

And I guess, we don't need to run `lunch` first when we just run `fastboot flashall -w` in the same terminal where we build the android system.